# Convert data row to column and show it month wise

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a following table:-

```
CREATE TABLE #TmpData (
 RType Varchar(10),
 Client VARCHAR(10),
 TRequest INT,
 Due INT,
 Month INT
  );

  INSERT INTO #TmpData VALUES ('P', 'Name1',54,67,1),('P', 'Name5',5,47,1),('A', 'Name6',3,90,1 ),('A', 'Name3',4,43,1 ),('P', 'Name1',0,10,2)
  ,('P', 'Name2',1,78,2),('P', 'Name4',54,67,3),('P', 'Name3',5,47,3),('A', 'Name6',3,90,3 ),('P', 'Name8',3,233,3 ),('P', 'Name1',23,457,4)
  ,('P', 'Name7',3,6,4 ),('P', 'Name8',65,548,4 ),('P', 'Name2',3,56,5 ),('P', 'Name3',65,87,6 ),('P', 'Name4',3,56,7 ),('P', 'Name9',65,87,7 )

 SELECT * FROM #TmpData
```

I want to Convert its data row wise to column and show it monthwise. I am attaching the screenshot of my resultset which I need.

[Result Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oo092.png)

**Here for example I have taken 7 months but it can go upto 12 months.**

Please Help.

Thanks

Comment: Look for [SQL pivot](https://modern-sql.com/use-case/pivot).

Comment: Can you please help with the solution, I am finding it difficult

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `CASE WHEN` with `SUM` function.

`CASE WHEN` compare the `month` then `SUM` that `TRequest` or `Due` `group by` by
`RType`,`Client`

```
SELECT RType,
       Client,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Month = 1 THEN TRequest ELSE 0 END) 'Jan Totle',
       SUM(CASE WHEN Month = 1 THEN Due ELSE 0 END) '#of Request',
       SUM(CASE WHEN Month = 2 THEN TRequest ELSE 0 END) 'Feb Totle',
       SUM(CASE WHEN Month = 2 THEN Due ELSE 0 END) '#of Request',
       SUM(CASE WHEN Month = 3 THEN TRequest ELSE 0 END) 'March Totle',
       SUM(CASE WHEN Month = 3 THEN Due ELSE 0 END) '#of Request',
       SUM(CASE WHEN Month = 4 THEN TRequest ELSE 0 END) 'April Totle',
       SUM(CASE WHEN Month = 4 THEN Due ELSE 0 END) '#of Request',
       SUM(CASE WHEN Month = 5 THEN TRequest ELSE 0 END) 'May Totle',
       SUM(CASE WHEN Month = 5 THEN Due ELSE 0 END) '#of Request',
       SUM(CASE WHEN Month = 6 THEN TRequest ELSE 0 END) 'June Totle',
       SUM(CASE WHEN Month = 6 THEN Due ELSE 0 END) '#of Request',
       SUM(CASE WHEN Month = 7 THEN TRequest ELSE 0 END) 'July Totle',
       SUM(CASE WHEN Month = 7 THEN Due ELSE 0 END) '#of Request',
       SUM(CASE WHEN Month = 8 THEN TRequest ELSE 0 END) 'Aug Totle',
       SUM(CASE WHEN Month = 8 THEN Due ELSE 0 END) '#of Request',
       SUM(CASE WHEN Month = 9 THEN TRequest ELSE 0 END) 'Sep Totle',
       SUM(CASE WHEN Month = 9 THEN Due ELSE 0 END) '#of Request',
       ....
FROM TmpData
GROUP BY RType,
       Client
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b5189/8)

**EDIT**

if you want to make `month` column dynamic, you can use dynamic pivot.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @Pivotcols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);



SET @Pivotcols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT 
                                ',SUM(CASE WHEN Month = ' + CAST(Month AS VARCHAR(5)) + ' THEN TRequest ELSE 0 END) as ''' + FORMAT(DATEADD(mm,Month,'1900-01-01'),'MMM') + ' Totle ''',
                                ',SUM(CASE WHEN Month = ' + CAST(Month AS VARCHAR(5)) + ' THEN Due ELSE 0 END) as ''' + FORMAT(DATEADD(mm,Month,'1900-01-01'),'MMM') + ' Totle '''
            FROM TmpData 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');


set @query = 'SELECT RType,Client, '+  @Pivotcols + ' FROM TmpData GROUP BY RType,Client'



execute(@query)
```

[SQLFIDDLE dynamic pivot](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ca4bfded02d03a851f4a7285d1122fbc)

Comment: Thanks for reply, Can I make month column dynamic, that is show only those month whose data is present like if August data is not present, then I don't want to show that column

Comment: @RahulAggarwal you can make month column dynamic, i edit my answer